# Hyperledger Composer CLI Ping to a Business Network returns AccessException

Tags: ping, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Im trying to learn Hyperledger Composer but seems to be a relatively new technology, i mean there are few tutorials and few solutions to a lot of questions, tutorial does not mention possible error case when following the commands and which means there are is also no solution for those errors.

I have joined the composer channel in their community chat, looks like its running in Discord or something, and asked the same question without a response, i have a better experience here in SO.

This is the problem: I have deployed my business network, installed it, started it, created my network admin card and imported it, then to test if everything is ok i have to command composer network ping --card NAME-OF-MY-ADMIN-CARD

And this error comes:

```
juan@JuanDeDios:~/proyectos/inovacion/a3-poliza-microservice$ composer network ping --card admin@a3-policy-microservice
Error: transaction returned with failure: AccessException: Participant 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#a3-policy-microservice@0.0.1'
Command failed
```

I think that it has to do something with the permission.acl file, and gave permission to everyone to everything so there would not be any restrictions to anyone, and tryied again, but failed.

So i thought i had to uninstall my business network and create it again, i deleted my .bna and my network.card files also so everything would be created again, but the same error result.

My other attempt was to update the business network, but didn't work, the same error happened and I'm sure i didn't miss any step from the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial). I do also followed the playground tutorial. What i have not done its to create another app with the Yeoman but i will do if i don't find a solution to this problem which would not require me to create another app.

This were my steps:
1-. Created my app with Yeoman

```
yo hyperledger-composer:businessnetwork
```

2-. Selected Apache-2.0 for my license
3-. Created a3-policy-microservice as the name of the business network
4-. Created org.microservice.policy (Yeah i switched names but Im totally aware)
5-. Generated my app with a template selecting the NO option

6-. Created my assets, participants and transactions
7-. Changed my permission rules to mine
8-. I generated the .bna file

```
composer archive create -t dir -n .
```

9-. Then installed my bna file

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile a3-policy-microservice@0.0.1.bna
```

10-. Then started my network and created my networkadmin card

```
composer network start --networkName a3-policy-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

11-. Imported my card

```
composer card import --file networkadmin.card
```

12-. Tried to ping my network

```
composer network ping --card admin@a3-poliza-microservice
```

And the error happens

Later i tried to create everything again shutting down my fabric and started it again and creating the network from the first step.

My other attempt was to change the permissions and upgrade my bna network, but it failed too. Im running out of options

Hope this description its not too long to ignore it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the question!

First possibility is that your network name is `a3-policy-network` but you're pinging a network called `a3-poliza-microservice` - once you do get the correct ACLs in place (currently, that's the error you're trying to resolve).

The procedure for upgrade would normally be the procedure below:

After your step 12  (where you can't ping the business network due to restrictive ACL conditions, assuming you are using the right network name) you would have:

13. Make the changes to to include your System ACLs this time eg.

/**
* Sample access control list.
*/

```
rule SystemACL {
description: "System ACL to permit all access"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "**"
action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
action: ALLOW
}
```

14. Update the "version" field in your existing `package.json` in your Business Network project directory (ie need to change it next increment - eg. update the version property from 0.0.1 to 0.0.2.)
15. From the same directory, run the following command:

    ```
    composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a a3-policy-network@0.0.2.bna
    ```
16. Now install the new business network code firstly:

    ```
    composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile a3-policy-network@0.0.2.bna
    ```
17. Then perform the requisite upgrade step (single '-' for short form of the parameter):

    ```
    composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n a3-policy-network -V 0.0.2
    ```
18. After a few seconds, ping the network again to see ACL changes are now in effect:

    ```
    composer network ping -c a3-policy-network
    ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i end up creating the whole application again since the step 1 with yeoman and now it worked, i was careful this time of not switching names, naming the folder, the business network and the org the same, but im pretty sure you are right, the network names are not the same, it should be a3-policy-microservice.

In a moment i will try to change my acces rules to see if the upgrade works.

Thank you!