# Hyperledger composer not accepting chaincode changes (Same version)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am deploying changes within the same version as the following **without** any errors:

```
#re-generating the updated bna file    
composer archive create -t dir -n .

#restarting the entire network
../../fabric-dev-servers/stopFabric.sh && ../../fabric-dev-servers/startFabric.sh

#installing the generated bna file
composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a network@0.0.1.bna

#starting the network again.
composer network start --networkName network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

I am not getting any error.
I can see the changes in the file `network@0.0.1.bna` using `VIM` as expected.

Did I miss something here?
Should I deploy differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes (you did / you should). Your script mentions "*re-generating the updated bna file"* so from that I assume you want to update your business network chaincode, one you previously deployed? What you've actually done in your script, by re-running `./startFabric.sh`  - is you will start up a WHOLE NEW FABRIC dev environment, with a peer(s) that no longer have any chaincode packages installed (and each time you run the current script, that's the case). I'm not sure you want to do this, if you're merely making 'chaincode changes' - then remove the ./startFabric.sh invocation for starters.

To upgrade a business network (eg, v0.0.1 as the initial install version in your package.json) previously installed - see step 14 onwards in ANSWER of this Stack Overflow -> [Hyperledger Composer CLI Ping to a Business Network returns AccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975866/hyperledger-composer-cli-ping-to-a-business-network-returns-accessexception/51983081#51983081) - it provides the correct steps for upgrade (so that you can see your 'chaincode changes', using the new version, eg. 0.0.2).

Composer is in line with the way Fabric works, with a new container for each new version. You can stop and remove the older container, and also remove the old image for that.

Comment: Thanks. that is working fine! Can this be automated? it's strange that I need to change the version in the package.json file on every character I change in the code

Comment: ok cool. Yes, you can automate. See last paragraph of my response - you can dev/test your business network, importing into Playground (web connector, something like a 'dev mode' that Fabric dev has), and differentiate that from a change-managed version, operating against a Fabric environment, to upgrade a business network in (say a test environment)

Comment: Yes, but that would be very long to deploy.  isn't there something like "build and run" similar to Java and c# where your code is immediately injected to the container. Will every change appear immediately? (just for dev). this is painfully slow now )-: thanks!

Comment: The only documented way would be to import your bna into playground and deploy to the web browser profile (a simulation of a fabric with a real composer runtime), make changes and upgrade which will be much faster than if you try to deploy to a real production mode fabric.